# Will using affine transform to shrink UIStepper as UIBarButtonItem disqualify my app?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uibarbuttonitem, usability, ui-guidelines

I'm considering shrinking a UIStepper by 15% and translating its X position in a nav bar (e.g. it's in a UINavBarItem with as a custom View), and to choose values that respect various screen sizes, to ensure usability is not broken. Although it will slightly reduce the hit pad area it is still quite functional and doesn't look bad.

While it may not be the ideal recommended by Apple's UI Guidelines, is it enough to get the app rejected?  What do I need to be aware of?